# Rspec testing ransack always returning all instances

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ransack

I would like to do a specific search using ransack but my test always returns all instances.

My test:

```
RSpec.describe UsersController, type: :controller do

describe "GET #index" do

context 'ransack search by email' do

  let!(:user1) { create(:user, email: 'user1@example.com') }
  let!(:user2) { create(:user, email: 'user2@example.com') }

  context 'finds specific user' do
    before { get :index, q: '2' }

    it "should find just one user" do
      expect(assigns(:users).first).to eq [user2]
    end

    it { should respond_with(:success) }
    it { should render_template(:index) }
  end
```

My controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @q ||= User.ransack(params[:q])
    @users = @q.result(distinct: true)
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The param q: should be like

```
q: {email_cont: '2'}
```